# comma separated field to compare in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched so much to find an answer but i can't.Here is my question
I have a table named main_table like this:

```
╔════╦════════════════╦
║ id ║    seat_id     ║
╠════╬════════════════╬
║  1 ║   274115,      ║
║  2 ║  274116,274117,║ 
║  3 ║ 274113,274114, ║
╚════╩════════════════╩
```

These seat_id's are primary key of another table named sub_table

```
╔═════════╦════════════════╦
║ seat_id ║    seat        ║
╠═════════╬════════════════╬
║  274115 ║     186        ║
║  274116 ║     187        ║ 
║  274117 ║     188        ║
║  274118 ║     159        ║
╚═════════╩════════════════╩
```

I want all the seat related to main_table's seat_id

```
╔════════════╗
║    seat    ║
╠════════════╣
║    186     ║
║    187     ║
║    188     ║
╚════════════╝
```

What i have tried so far is with sub query

```
select seat from sub_table where seat_id in(select seat_id from main_table)
```

That's not helping me

Comment: Is there a particular reason that your `main_table` has multiple values in the `seat_id` column? This violates first normal form. Ideally, you'd put each unique value in its own row  - then you could use regular `JOINS` (or your existing `IN` statement).

Comment: Normalize your tables and it's a simple `select set from normalized_table where seat_id in (select seat_id from sub_table`

Comment: There is a reason because that are seats under one ticket

Comment: Just because multiple seats are reserved under 1 ticket doesn't mean that the table can't be normalised. You could use a composite primary key with the columns that you have now, and put each seat on a different row

Comment: @Ben ya but it is too late that table has already over 200000 entries

Comment: It's never to late, now it's only 200000 rows. With increasing row count you will encounter performance problems as you can't add an index. So better change it now and learn how to avoid the same wrong data model in future.

Comment: @dnoeth I will try that thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`FIND_IN_SET`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT seat
FROM sub_table AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM main_table AS t2
              WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t1.seat_id, t2.seat_id) <> 0)
```

However, I would suggest normalizing table `main_table`, as it is always a bad idea to store comma separated values in a single field like you do.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bd03/3)

Comment: `SELECT 1   FROM main_table`  what does it means sir?

Comment: @SanoojT It doesn't really mean anything. When a `SELECT` query is used in the context of an `EXISTS` operator, then the expression it defines evaluates to either `true` or `false` *irrespective* of the fields specified in the `SELECT` clause of the query. So it suffices to just use `1` in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you sir,You answered my two questions currect  including this

Comment: Can you please give us back the real Giorgos Betsos - you know, the one who would never seriously suggest this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all u didnt normalize your table so u cant use joins 
   and   query u used "select seat_id from main_table" --> is not an array .
Try to pass array

```
select seat from sub_table where seat_id in($array)
```